# Storing currency with variable floating point in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, money

We are working with currency and handle currencies from various countries. As a result, we may work with currencies that require no decimal values, two decimal places, three, sometimes four.

We also store taxes that are derived from individual items, and we usually store them with higher precision than the currency specifies (eg: taxes for Canadian dollars would be stored to 4 decimal places)

What would be an appropriate way to store these values? I have read that many people store them as integers in the lowest denomination (eg: dollars would be stored in cents), but the 4-decimal taxes would not work out very well.

Comment: Integer with implied decimals. No reason why you can't structure your tax values to have a different number of implied decimals - just takes a bit of thinking schema design-wise

Comment: Floating point data type should not be used for currency values, as it is by definition an approximation. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency

Comment: @Phil So for example, multiplying it by a sufficiently large decimal number which will cover all of these odd cases (eg: 1000000) and then remember to divide it afterwards?

Comment: @MxyL Say you want to represent $1.23. You'd store it as 123. Implied decimals would be 2, so multiply by 100. Code-wise, it'd always be value*10^implied decimals ( value times ten to the power of implied decimals). Very easy to code for. It's a system I like, but may not suit everyone